# Trying to send over routine data with api

Tags: javascript, api, router

I am building a fitness tracker through a class, it gives me built in tests to use as well. I am having an issue with passing this one in specific. I shortened the test specs for convenience.

```
Expected[{"activities": [{"activityId": 3,

Received {"publicRoutines": [{"activities": [{"activityId": 3,
```

```
1. Gets a list of public routines for a particular user.
2. Gets a list of all routines for the logged in user
```

I understand that the publicRoutines are sent in the res.send() but without the curly brackets, it sends over a failed test that is in my catch. Is there a way to send over both of these functions in my code to match the expected result?

```
usersRouter.get(`/:username/routines`,async(req,res) =>{
    const username = req.params.username
    try{
        if(username){
            const userRoutines = await getAllRoutinesByUser({username});
            const publicRoutines = await getPublicRoutinesByUser({username})
            console.log(publicRoutines, userRoutines)
            res.send({publicRoutines, userRoutines})
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }catch(error){
        throw Error('Failed to get', error)
    }
})
```